# How to check if value is defined in rego?

Tags: open-policy-agent

I want to check if a variable is defined in OPA policy.

```
> subject
1 error occurred: 1:1: rego_unsafe_var_error: var subject is unsafe
```

Is there a function to check if a variable is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `show` command to show active module definition.

```
> show
package repl

b = 45534543

a = 3423

sites = [
    {"name": "prod"},
    {"name": "smoke1"},
    {"name": "dev"},
]
```

You will find the list of defined variables here.